# Build to iOS error

Tags: ios, coronasdk

I am currently having a problem building for iOS, for Android I have no problem at all.

The console always says CFStreamError, I believe what cause the error is when I updated my Xcode, but what could be the possible solution here?. Because if my proxy server is the error, I couldn't have build for Android, this only occurs in iOS. Thanks in advance

More Info here:

**I have successfully build for prev Xcode version. this happened after I updated my Xcode.**

> Platform: MAC OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
>
> Corona BUILD Version : Version 2015.2545 (2015.1.24)
>
> Prev Xcode version: 5.something
>   Current Xcode Version: 6.4

More Console Info here:

```
response: {
"/FaultCode" = "-65794";
"/FaultExtra" =     {
    domain = "-1";
    error = "-65795";
    msg = "The server did not return a 'text/xml' response.";
};
"/FaultString" = "/CFStreamFault";
"/WSDebugInHeaders" =     {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-httpd-fastphp";
    Date = "Mon, 17 Aug 2015 05:45:15 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
};
"/kWSHTTPResponseMessage" = "<CFHTTPMessageRef 0x7f8653ee9640(0x7f8653ee9650)> { parsed response, url = https://developer.coronalabs.com/services/xmlrpc, status = 200 }";
"/kWSResultIsFault" = 1;
}
```

**Update:**

- Right now it randomly wants me to login before building. I input the correct password(I triple checked it) but still it says login failed in the console. Then after a while still the previous problem still occurs. Whenever I restart corona, it still says that my password is incorrect.
- I tried to deauthorize, but I think corona won't detect my password correctly, for I wasn't able to deauthorize. I restarted my mac, still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error needs to have your account reset, but before we get there, Apple has changed the rules and you have to build with an Xcode that matches the iOS version you're targeting.

That is you need Xcode 6 to build iOS 8, you will need Xcode 7 to build iOS 9. I can't determine what iOS version 2545 is targeting, but it's two public builds old. 2646 is the current public build and daily builds are now over 2700. I would recommend updating to at least 2646 and then make sure your Xcode is up to date.

2645 is building with iOS 8.3 which needs Xcode 6.3.  2702 is iOS 8.4 and needs Xcode 6.4. These have to be matched up.

Do that and see if it solves your problem.